# Как добавить данные из таблицы MySQL в таблицу WPF?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, база-данных

Необходимо по запросу из textbox выводить таблицу из MySql. Предполагаю вывод в DataGrid, но не понимаю как это реализовать.

DataGrid принимает типизированную коллекцию. Однако создать класс для объекта таблицы не представляется возможным, т.к. не исключается добавление новых полей.

То, что смог выдавить:

```
string connstr = "server=localhost; user=root; database=lab_3; password=0000";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr))
      {
        conn.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM new_table;";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        if (reader.HasRows)
         {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
             int index = 0;

             arrayList.Add(reader[index]);
           }
           grid.ItemsSource = arrayList;
           reader.Close();
         }
```

Буду рад любым предложениям и идеям!

Comment: *DataGrid принимает типизированную коллекцию* – с чего вы взяли? Вроде можно привязать и DataTable

Comment: Разбей вопрос на два: как **считать** данные из базы, и как **отобразить** данные с помощью WPF. Какой из пунктов у тебя **не** получается?

Comment: @MikhailIonkin Не получается отобразить данные в WPF. Со считыванием вроде бы проблем нет, однако я не уверен, что мой способ считывания данных верный для этой ситуации. Возможно есть другой способ, с помощью которого можно представить данные сразу в необходимом или более удобном для разбора виде, но я такой не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
datagrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
datagrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```